# Spark (Scala) udf to modify map in column of dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe that looks something like this.
The `tfs` column is a map of String to Long and the `weights` are floats

```
+----------+---+------------------------+------------------+
|term      |df |tfs                     |weight            |
+----------+---+------------------------+------------------+
|keyword1  |2  |{2.txt -> 2, 1.txt -> 2}|1.3               |
|keyword2  |1  |{2.txt -> 1}            |0.6931471805599453|
|keyword3  |2  |{2.txt -> 1, 1.txt -> 2}|0.52343473        |
+----------+---+------------------------+------------------+
```

I would like to combine the last two columns by multiplying each value in the `tfs`map by its respective weight to get something like

```
+----------+---+------------------------------------------+
|term      |df |weighted-tfs                              |
+----------+---+------------------------------------------+
|keyword1  |2  |{2.txt -> 2.6, 1.txt -> 2.6}              |
|keyword2  |1  |{2.txt -> 0.6931471805599453}             |
|keyword3  |2  |{2.txt -> 0.52343473, 1.txt -> 1,04686946}|
+----------+---+------------------------------------------+
```

My guess is that it would be quite simle to write a udf for this, but I'm quite experienced in both Spark and Scala, so I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Pls show some output.

Comment: @thebluephantom what do you mean? I posted the output of my dataframe.show() that's all I have

Comment: Expected  output

Comment: @thebluephantom sorry, my bad

Comment: spark version ?

Comment: You were wll helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map_from_arrays`,`map_keys` & `map_values` functions.

Try below code.

```
val finalDF = df
.withColumn(
    "weighted-tfs",
    map_from_arrays(
        map_keys($"tfs"),
        expr("transform(map_values(tfs),i -> i * weight)")
    )
)
```

Output

```
finalDF.show(false)

+--------+---+------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------+
|term    |df |tfs                     |weight            |product                                   |
+--------+---+------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------+
|keyword1|2  |[2.txt -> 2, 1.txt -> 2]|1.3               |[2.txt -> 2.6, 1.txt -> 2.6]              |
|keyword2|1  |[2.txt -> 1]            |0.6931471805599453|[2.txt -> 0.6931471805599453]             |
|keyword3|2  |[2.txt -> 1, 1.txt -> 2]|0.52343473        |[2.txt -> 0.52343473, 1.txt -> 1.04686946]|
+--------+---+------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------+
```